# $id|_V$ stands for?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Sorry if it can sound like a dumb question but this is the first time i see this notation.

$id|_V$ stands for?  And $f|_W$ ?

I suppose that $W$ and $V$ are spaces or subspaces but the rest?

Comment: $id|_V$ is the restriction of the identity map to $V$, and $f|_W$ is the restriction of $f$ to $W$.

Comment: Problem solved thanks.

Comment: @Spenser, since you got here first, could you post that as an answer so this question doesn't appear unanswered?

Comment: @MarkS. Done.${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$id|_V$ is the restriction of the identity map to $V$, and $f|_W$ is the restriction of $f$ to $W$.